# Why doesn't this print 0 through 999?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, posix

On Linux, why does this print `0` and hang rather than printing 0 up to 999?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n = 1000;
    int fromparent[2];
    int fromchild[2];
    int *x = 0;

    pipe(fromparent);
    pipe(fromchild);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        /* child */
        while (1) {
            read(fromparent[0], x, 1);
            write(fromchild[1], x, 1);
        }
    } else {
        /* parent */
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%d\n",  i);
            write(fromparent[1], x, 1);
            read(fromchild[0], x, 1);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: the return value from fork() can be -1 if it failed. You're mishandling that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simple: you pass a null pointer to `read` and `write`.

Change the definition of `x` from `int *x = 0;` to:

```
char x[1] = { 0 };
```

As posted, the behavior is somewhat counterintuitive:

- passing a null pointer to `write` causes it to return `-1` immediately, setting `errno` to `EINVAL`.
- conversely, passing a null pointer to `read` causes it to wait for input and only return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINVAL` once input is available.  This is causing both processes to block on the `read` calls.

Here is a simple test to illustrate this behavior:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    errno = 0;
    n = read(0, NULL, 1);
    printf("n=%d, errno=%d\n", n, errno);
    return 0;
}
```

This program waits for input if run from the console and prints `n=-1, errno=14` after the user hits <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Conversely, it prints `n=0, errno=0` when standard input is redirected from `/dev/null`.

Comment: Or maybe `char x[1] = { 0 };`

Comment: @SteveSummit: good point, although it does not matter much in this particular case as the contents of `x` is not actually used.

Comment: Wait ... shouldn't that cause it to go around the loop really fast as read is just going to set EINVAL or something like that?

Comment: @Joshua: Interesting remark: it does so for `write`, but not for `read`. See updated answer.